# Adding a UIViewController to UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a `UIViewCOntroller` and i have added a lot of UI components to it, labels, text fields, etc..

Now, i need to add some more fields to it. and i have figured out that i don't have any space in my viewcontroller to add any. So i was thinking of adding a scrollView to solve this problem. Is there away where i could add my `UIViewController` which is holding all the UI components to a `UIScrollView`.

How can i do this programatically ?

Comment: You're confusing views and view controllers, which are not the same thing. Make sure you fully understand the difference. For example, there's no class in UIKit called UIScrollViewController.

Comment: Thankyou for pointing it out, i have edited my question accordingly

Answer (score 1):

For exemple if you are in A viewController methode :

```
UIViewController * v =  [[UIViewController alloc] init];
UIScrollView * sc =  [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
```

...use setFrame for v and sc frames

```
[sc setScrollEnabled:YES];
[sc setContentSize:2000];
[sc addSubview:v.view];

[self.view addSubview:sc];
```

Comment: @Illep : I added UIViewController's view : v.view

Comment: wait.. self.view is to what i have added all my buttons, text fields etc. so what does v.view contain (does it contain the buttons, text fields i added)? and ultimately will i be able to scroll the view without making any change to the UI components in the self.view ?

Comment: So just add an UIScollView in self.view, and add all your components in sc.view. 

Else, when you make an instance with your current UIViewController named "ExempleViewController" (this one contains all your components) juste add exempleViewController.view in UIScrollView instance view that you create at the same level.

Answer (score 0):

why not add all your controls on UISCrollView and then add this UIScrollView to UIViewController's view?

Comment: That's alot of work, isn't there any simpler way of doing this ? the problem is that i have not used the interface builder to create the UI's, everything is created by code, so it will take awhile to make these changes. So isn't there any other way of doing this ?

Comment: other way -  you can add a UIScrollView on another UIViewController and add your current view controller's instance to UIScrollView.. but you can get in trouble later!

Answer (score 0):

UIViewController in iphone or ipod ,supposed to be fullscreen
you shouldn't add a UIViewController to UIScrollView
you can add a UIScrollView to UIViewController
and move all your component in UIViewController into UIScrollView

Comment: @Beber has done above is to add a ViewController to become subView of UISCrollView

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add a a scrollview to a viewController. You could add the master view of the view controller into a scrollview.

Comment: What do you think about @Beber's answer ? i am not in my Mac now so i can't try it out, but according to his code he has added a UIViewController to a UIScrollView. Your comments ?

Comment: In his code he hasn't added a UIViewController into a ScrollView he has added a ViewController's master view to a ScrollView - which is what I suggested. Views can be added to views. ViewControllers are not added to views, but their views are.