# Adding UIScrollView to a UIViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I have a `UIViewController`, and I want to add a `UIScrollView` to it (enable scroll support), is it possible?

I know it is possible, if you have a `UIScrollView` to add a `UIViewController` to it, but I'm interested also if reverse was true, if I cann add a `UIScrollView` to an existing `UIViewController`, such that I get scrolling feature.

*Edit*

I think I have found an answer: [Adding a UIViewController to UIScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8607135/adding-a-uiviewcontroller-to-uiscrollview)

Comment: You can add UIScrollView to view of UIViewController & you can view of UIViewController to UIScrollView

Comment: Before doing something like that, I would look what is a controller and what is a view. They are really different things.

Comment: you can add scrollview to a view controller and view controllers to a scrollview, just add your scrollview as a subview to your existing viewController

Comment: I know what is a view and a view controller and why is it relevant in my case?

Comment: @user1903992 you can add a view to a scroll view as subview or vica versa. But not a view controller. A view controller is a object which has usually (at least one) views as ivar.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

An `UIViewController` has a `view` property. So, you can add a `UIScrollView` to its `view`. In other words, you can add the scroll view to the view hierarchy.

This is can achieved by code or through XIB. In addition, you can register the view controller as the delegate for your scroll view. In this way, you can implement methods for performing different functionalities. See `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol.

```
// create the scroll view, for example in viewDidLoad method
// and add it as a subview for the controller view

[self.view addSubview:yourScrollView];
```

You could also override `loadView` method for `UIViewController` class and set the scroll view as the main view for the controller you are considering.

*Edit*

I created a little sample for you. Here, you have a scroll view as a child of the view of a `UIViewController`. The scroll view has two views as children: `view1` (blue color) and `view2` (green color).

Here, I suppose you can scroll in only one direction: horizontally or vertically. In the following, if you scroll horizontally, you can see that the scroll view works as expected.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIScrollView* scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
    scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
    scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width * 2, self.view.bounds.size.height);    
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];

    float width = 50;
    float height = 50;
    float xPos = 10;
    float yPos = 10;

    UIView* view1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xPos, yPos, width, height)];
    view1.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];    
    [scrollView addSubview:view1];

    UIView* view2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width + xPos, yPos, width, height)];
    view2.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];    
    [scrollView addSubview:view2];
}
```

If you need to scroll only vertically you can change as follows:

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height * 2);
```

Obviously, you need to rearrange the position of `view1` and `view2`.

P.S. Here I'm using ARC. If you don't use ARC, you need to explicitly `release` alloc-init objects.

Comment: Hi I thought about this, adding the UIScrollView as a subview to my ViewController, just I was doubting if that would allow the "scroll feature"... (you know, since I was adding it as a "sub view" ..)

Comment: @user1903992 Sure, if the scroll view is added as a subview, it will be on top on this. Consider the view hierarchy like a stack. The scroll view will respond to user interaction.

Comment: So, whenever you are adding a view it *sits* on top of it??? hm..... interesting... didn't know that... seems like a stack indeed.

Comment: @user1903992 like flexaddicted already explained, you can not add the UIScrollView as a subview to your ViewController. You can just add the scrollview to the view of your viewcontroller as subview.

Comment: I would suggest to read http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html Hope that helps. About your question, yes. But you can also change that stack.

Comment: Yes, that was a typo, actually I was implying to a self.view addSubview, which means adding UIScrollView as a subview to the view of the ViewController.. but still not working.. :|

Comment: @user1903992 You should provide some code. What does not work?

Comment: This is the code I Have in my view controller.  

` UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 568)];`
   ` scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;`
   ` scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(768, 1004); `
  `  [self.view addSubview:scrollView];`

Comment: @user1903992 I added an edit for you. Hope it helps. If you find it useful, please mark as answered (up vote too if you want). Cheers.

Comment: Can I override in the storyboard the view class type to UIScrollView and nothing more? If I do it, the inspection view don't show the UIScrollView properties, show like it was an UIView...

Comment: What a useful answer! After days trying to get Apple’s sample code to do what I needed, this simple explanation, with a code example that works in iOS 10.3, put me on the right track. Thanks