# Add a ScrollView to existing View

Tags: ios, swift, scrollview

I'm developing a little app in Swift 2.0. I have a View with the following hierarchy:

[image]

Now, the elements placed in this view can't be displayed entirely in it, so I would like to use a `ScrollView` in order to be able to scroll all the content.

How I can embed all the content of my `View`to a new `ScrollView`? Can I do this programmatically by code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding UIScrollView to a UIViewController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14055950/adding-uiscrollview-to-a-uiviewcontroller)

Comment: You can add the scrollView from the storyboard, but once you do this, you have to set the constraint for all the view you add inside scrollView. You cant just add scrollView and expect that it will scroll.

Comment: To Embed scrollView select all views you want to add to ScrollView and, go to Editor - EmbedIn - ScrollView.

Comment: I tried to embed all view elements in the ScrollView, how said by @BharatModi but it does not scroll. Have I add anything else? I would like, if possible, find a solution "by code" which avoid me to set again all contraints.

Comment: Follow the steps mentioned in the url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35624873/ios-scrollview-needs-constraint-for-y-position-or-height/35625897#35625897

Comment: The question mentioned above is not a duplicate. It's a very old question and the answer is in Obj-C and for autoresizing.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

**UPDATE: There's an easier way to do this which I didn't know when I posted this answer**

1) Go to the viewcontroller on the storyboard and click on something in it and press `Command + A`. This will select all the elements in the view.

2) Go to `Editor -> Embed In -> Scroll View`. This will embed all the labels, views, etc into a scrollView.

3) Select the `scrollview` that you just embedded. Press `Control` and drag it to the respective class file of the viewcontroller and create an outlet `scrollView`.

4) Add this to your `viewDidLoad()`

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height+100)
```

Make sure the height for the **contentSize is more than the size of your view.**

**ADDING SCROLLVIEW MANUALLY**

1) Drag and drop a `scrollview` from the Object Library onto your `viewcontroller` in the storyboard and create an outlet to your program as 'scrollView'.

2)  Click on your `viewcontroller` and go to the size inspector and note down the width and height.

3) Click on your `scrollview` and set the `width` and `height` the same as the `viewcontroller`. and set the `X` and `Y` values to 0

4) Click on the `scrollView` and drag it a little bit to the side

5) Press `Command+A` to select all the elements including `scrollView`. Press `Command` and click on the `scrollView` to deselect the `ScrollView`

6)You will have all the elements except the `scrollView` selected now. Now click and drag them into the scrollView.

[image: Moving into scrollView]

7) Now click on the `scrollView` and set the `X` and `Y` values to 0 from the Size Inspector.

8) Add this to your `viewDidLoad()`

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height+100)
```

**Make sure the height for the contentSize is more than the size of your view.**

That should create a scrollView for your view. Some of the elements **might be in a slightly different position**. You can easily fix them by moving them on your storyBoard.

Comment: Have I set again all constrains after the embedding of my view element into the scrollView?

Comment: I don't think so. You just have to set the constraints of the scrollview.

Comment: Awesome response. Saves a lot of trouble, in keeping the existing constraints in tact, however, all the constraints between the individual elements to the superview will go away as the scrollview is added in between. So before it was Superview->Individual elements and now it's Superview->Scrollview->Individual elements. So all the constraints initial ones between elements and superview will now be replaced by scrollview and elements and we also need to add new constraints between the scrollview and the superview.

Comment: For now (Xcode 8, iOS 10) you should use `self.view.frame.size.width` & `self.view.frame.size.height` properties.

Comment: Just what I needed. Although had to change `CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height+300)` to `CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height+300)`

Answer (score 8):

It can be done even simpeler than ebby94's answer.

1) Go to the viewcontroller on the storyboard and click on something in it and press Command + A. This will select all the elements in the view.

2) Go to Editor -> Embed In -> Scroll View. This will embed all the labels, views, etc into a scrollView.

3) Set the constraints of the Scroll View to the View's edges.

And you're good to go! No need for an outlet.

Comment: On step 3 I set 4 constraints: leading, trailing, top layout guide, bottom layout guide. I get a warning that says, "Scrollable content size is ambiguous for 'Scroll View'."

Comment: Are you sure that you did all the previous steps right?

Comment: Editor > Embed In > Scroll View was disabled, so this didn't work for me.

Comment: @Dale Take care, that you don't select the safe area!

Comment: @MarkMoeykens The trick is to add View to the scrollView and add the content to the View! Look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54577278/5056173

Answer (score 3):

**If you are using Snapkit or creating programmatically.**

```
class ScrollViewController: UIViewController {

lazy var contentViewSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height + 320) //Step One

lazy var scrollView : UIScrollView = {
    let view = UIScrollView(frame : .zero)
    view.frame = self.view.bounds
    view.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
    view.contentSize = contentViewSize
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    return view
}()

lazy var containerView : UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.frame.size = contentViewSize
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    return view
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {

    self.view.addSubview(scrollView)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(containerView)

    //Now Set Add your Constraints in the container View.

}
}
```

*Above accepted answer explanation is enough to achieve the scroll view but I would prefer to create my complete application programatically and I don't use storyboards in my project. This code is for the folks who don't prefer to use storyboards.*

**Explanation**

**Step One:** Determine your content Size. Here I am taking Exact width and adding 320 more to the height of the screen.

**Step Two:** Create a scroll view and add desire behaviour of the scroll view. Now, the contentSize of the scroll view should be same as the contentSize you've created above at step one.

**By Following Step one and Step Two. You Will be able to set a scroll view on the top of the view. But If you want to add a stretching behaviour then You should follow Step Three**

**Step Three:** Create a container view of the same size of the contentView which you've calculated in step one and set it to the frame of the containerView. By doing this you'll be able to achieve stretching header and footer behaviour in your screen.

**Please read make sure to add constraints in the same order as it is set.**

**Answer Edits are welcome.**

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I needed to add scrollview to the existing view.But my main container view has a lots of view inside it. And they were connected to each other. So i was afraid. Finally i did it. the process given below.

1. Duplicate your View (root View). For this first select the root view then press Command + D
2. Now delete all the child view view inside the root view
3. Now add a scroll view to the root view and set constraint to 0,0,0,0
4. Now add the duplicate(That you duplicated) view to the scroll view and set constraints to 0,0,0,,0 also set the height that you want.
5. Set width of the duplicate view by equal width with the root view.
6. Now select the viewController, go the size inspector, select free form size. Then set the height that you entered with duplicate view.
7. You have almost done. Now you have to connect the child view with outlet or action that you gave in the viewController class.

Thats all.

Answer (score 1):

Selecting all elements and embedding scroll view (editor->embed in->scrollView) works fine.

Adding constraint is much more easy by selecting the constraint warning (Add Missing Constraints).

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. Command A and Command X to specific view controller in StoryBoard. After that take scroll view. On scroll view, just take one view with view controller view height and width equal to scroll View width. Again do Command V and rearrange the constraints. Your problem will be solved.