# Adding scrollview to a view

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have tried [Adding UIScrollView to a UIViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14055950/adding-uiscrollview-to-a-uiviewcontroller), and I can never get my view to move down when I scroll, either on a simulator on a real device.  I have also tried increasing the size, so my code is as follows:

```
+(void)addScrollViewToView:(UIView *)view
{
    UIScrollView* scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, view.bounds.size.width * 2, view.bounds.size.height * 2)];
    scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
    scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(view.bounds.size.width * 2, view.bounds.size.height * 2);
    [view insertSubview:scrollView atIndex:0];
    //[view sendSubviewToBack:scrollView]; - commented out
}
```

It is called within viewDidLoad like so:

```
@implementation MyLoginViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
    [Utils addScrollViewToView:self.view];

    self.passwordTextField.secureTextEntry = YES;

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                   initWithTarget:self
                                   action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];

} // viewDidLoad method ends here
```

There is never any response when I try and scroll up with my mouse on a simulator.  There is a background image to my view controller that I created using a storyboard.  Would changing the index make any difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What did the trick was adding the view to the scrollview.

I.e.:

View >
ScrollView >
View that I wanted to scroll

Not:

View that I wanted to scroll >
ScrollView.

Answer (score 2):

It happen because you add gesture recognizer. Gesture recognizer blocks and not pass your touch.
You can make this for dismiss keyboard with UIScrollView:

```
+(void)addScrollViewToView:(UIView *)view
{
   // your code
   scrollView.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeOnDrag;
}
```

And remove UITapGestureRecognizer.

Answer (score 1):

Or is it because your frame size is the same as your content size? The scroll view will only scroll if its content is bigger than its frame.